# Сколько не пытался семейство font не работает в input через css. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, шрифты

```
        <input type="button" value="Бандит" onclick="javascript:img.src='img/bandit.png'">
        <input type="button" value="Бандит" onclick="javascript:img.src='img/fermer.png'">
        <input type="button" value="Бандит" onclick="javascript:img.src='img/shluha.png'">
        <input type="button" value="Бандит" onclick="javascript:img.src='img/vrach.png'">
       <input type="button" value="Бандит" onclick="javascript:img.src='img/shahter.png'">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: При чём тут семейство font через css если Вы картинку меняете?

Comment: так я хочу поменять стили текста-_-

Comment: Так покажите в вопросе что и где Вы желаете поменять и как Вы это делали и что не получилось

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в css:

```
input {
        font-family: шрифт;
}
```